# Blindly dd'ing faulty drive to new drive

Tags: hard-disk, dd, rescue

I have a faulty 320GB drive which has reading errors in samish GB positions but the exact positions vary. I am ok with probability of errors, this is out of question here.

First of all I was surprised with that I need `conv=sync` for `conv=noerror` being actually useful but ok, I have spare time to grow new foot. I found it because of `file -s /dev/sdc*` did not give any sensible output for last partitions (i.e. same as for source drive), it said `data` instead. However, I did not get any practical improvement after I added `sync` to my command line: the `file -s` output still makes no sense except for first partition which does not contain errors in FS description section so `file -s` command detects FS correctly. I confirm erratic copying with `mount -o ro` for both drives and comparing `md5sum`s for all files (but directory structure alone is erratic).

I am trying to dd it to new bigger drive this way:

```
dd if=/dev/sda3 conv=noerror,sync bs=1M of=/dev/sdc3 2> /part3_log
grep -oPaz '[[:digit:]]*(?=\+[[:digit:]]+ records out\n)' </part3_log >/part3_log_bads # parsing is ok for this specific case
rm /part3_log_01
for i in $(cat /part3_log_bads); do dd if=/dev/sda3 conv=noerror,sync bs=1M of=/dev/sdc3 skip=$((i-1)) seek=$((i-1)) count=1 2>>/part3_log_01; done # retrying erratic blocks. i-1 because of number of records is written after erratic block was padded and written. noerror does not make any practical difference here.
```

I get this output for each erratic block in `/part3_log` (as expected):

```
dd: error reading ‘/dev/sda3’: Input/output error
71051+3 records in  <<<<<<<<< second number increments from 0 after each erratic block indicating partial read, this is expected
71054+0 records out
74505519104 bytes (75 GB) copied, 2546,96 s, 29,3 MB/s
```

And I get this strange output (speed difference is expected) for all blocks in `/part3_log_01`:

```
1048576 bytes (1,0 MB) copied, 6,5663 s, 160 kB/s
0+1 records in
0+0 records out
0 bytes (0 B) copied, 6,41877 s, 0,0 kB/s
0+1 records in
1+0 records out
1048576 bytes (1,0 MB) copied, 7,42028 s, 141 kB/s
1+0 records in
1+0 records out
```

What draws my attention is that almost each input record is read partially while there are no errors reported despite them actually happening (I see them in `dmesg`). There are no error being reported for `sdc` (as expected, it's a new drive).

So, ho do I blindly copy faulty drive and then retry the faulty records? My approach seems to fail at two points:

- it fails to copy data without shift occuring after erratic blocks (despite `conv=sync` being present)
- it fails to report errors while retrying bad blocks.

P.S. I would like to do it with `dd` only. Using `ddrescue` is problematic ATM.

P.P.S. It's Debian 8.7.1 and dd 8.23

Comment: You should probably run `partprobe` after copying over an entire drive so that the kernel knows about the new partition layout.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick I forgot about it but new partition table was in effect after first time I rewritten it. It probably refreshes periodically. I did replug my HDD after my very first attempts and never changed MBR since then so it's definitely not an issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try ddrescue (gddrescue in most distros):

GNU ddrescue - Data recovery tool.  Copies data from one file or block device to another, trying to rescue the good parts first in case of read errors.

Comment: I would like to do it with dd unless I absolutely need `ddrescue`.

Comment: @EuriPinhollow you absolutely need to use `ddrescue`. Really.